# How to create a measure to get the maximum or minimum value from all the rows from a table in Power BI by filtering a column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard, business-intelligence, measure

I have a data set as shown uploaded in Power BI.
My data source is called `node_balance_t`.

From this data table, I want to get the max load and min load parameters by filtering column `Type` and selecting only `inflow` parameter, and then getting the max and min values by comparing the `Value` column for all the rows for a particular `Node`.

While trying to create a measure, I can't select a column from `node_balance_t` like doing node_balance_t["Type"]?
[image]

How can this be done by using a measure in Power BI?

Comment: Most likely you need to add in an aggregator, link MAX. MIN, SUM, etc... `MIN(tableName[columnName])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a Measure using MAXX and MINX functions respectively. Inside these functions, I had to filter the Type column as shown below:

```
MinLoad = 
   CALCULATE(
       MINX(
           FILTER(
               node_balance_t,
               node_balance_t[Type] = "inflow"
           ),
           node_balance_t[Value]
       )
   )
```

Comment: The same can be written as `CALCULATE(MIN(node_balance_t[Value), node_balance_t[Type] = "inflow") ` which is the effectively the same.